# How do I pass a json body request to api in a map string data structure in Golang?

Tags: api, go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I am new to golang and grpc, need guidance and clarification. I have below definition as a parameter to call a POST request for an external API.

```
    params := map[string]string{
    "movie":       movie,
    "seat":         seat,
    "pax": fmt.Sprint(pax),
    "class":      class,
}
```

In proto file, I have below:

```
message TicketData {
    string movie= 1;
    string seat= 2;
    uint32 pax= 3;
    string class = 4;
}

message SearchMovieRequest {
    TicketData data= 1;
}
```

However in POSTMAN (grpc request), the body request is showing below:

```
{
    "data": 
        {
            "movie": "abc",
            "seat": "123",
            "pax": 2,
            "class ": "b""
        }
   
}
```

the request body should be below:

```
{
    "data": **[**
        {
            "movie": "abc",
            "seat": "123",
            "pax": 2,
            "class ": "b""
        }
    **]** - missing brackets in my json body
}
```

I have tried using structpb and also map string interface. It doesn't seem to work. Any pointer will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `data` field to be `repeated TicketData`.

See e.g. [Specifying Field Rules](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying_field_rules) in the Protobuf [Language Guide (proto3)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3).

Specifically:

```
message TicketData {
    string movie= 1;
    string seat= 2;
    uint32 pax= 3;
    string class = 4;
}

message SearchMovieRequest {
    repeated TicketData data= 1;
}
```

> **NOTE** Although you include protobuf definitions, your examples are JSON. Protobuf implementations usually include automatic mappings between protobuf and JSON which is -- I assume -- what you're presenting.